# Java drawing String in JPanel

Tags: java, methods, jpanel, draw

I am complete Java noob and this question will be very easy. I did try to find answer across whole internet but, nothing was particularly what I need (if you know any tutorial pages for this subject please post link I would be very grateful.)

Basically I am trying to draw string in my DrawPanel. I know I need to call method somewhere in order to do so but I have no idea where. My draw panel has method:

```
public void drawGuessWord(Graphics g){
    WordsList guessWord = new WordsList();
    String word = guessWord.pickWord();
    g.drawString(word, 20, 20);
}
```

And I want to call that method so it would draw string inside DrawPanel.

Just in case this is my whole DrawPanel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    DrawPanel(){
        Border raisedbevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
        Border loweredbevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    }

    public void drawGuessWord(Graphics g){
        WordsList guessWord = new WordsList();
        String word = guessWord.pickWord();
        g.drawString(word, 20, 20);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
  g.drawString(word, 20, 20);
}
```

Comment: Can we, please, not overrde paint (unless absolutely required); better to use paintComponent. Also, we should be calling super.paint(g); ... IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer true, paintComponent is safer, i believe - thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to MimiEAM's solution, you might like to take a read of

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)